# How to replace arbitrary string in path via RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace a segment of a path in a string with another string. I have a feeling that RegEx would be the best way to do this but don't know how. I would like to replace xxxxx with another string:

```
resources/audio/xxxxx/someaudio.mp3
```

The root path of "resources/audio/" will always remain the same, but I am trying to replace the parent folder of the audio file. The audio file is arbitrary and can change. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this:

```
var newFolder = "yyyy";
var r = "resources/audio/xxxxx/someaudio.mp3".replace(/(resources\/audio\/).*(\/.*)/g, '$1' + newFolder + '$2');
console.log(r);
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qD25f/).

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace` method with capturing group:

```
> 'resources/audio/xxxxx/someaudio.mp3'.replace(/\bxxxxx\/([^/]+)$/, 'yyyy/$1')
"resources/audio/yyyy/someaudio.mp3"
> 'resources/audio/xxxxx/anotheraudio.mp3'.replace(/\bxxxxx\/([^/]+)$/, 'yyyy/$1')
"resources/audio/yyyy/anotheraudio.mp3"
```

`([^/]+)` match filename and captured as group 1. This group 1 is referenced as `$1` in replacement string.

---

Or use positive lookahead:

```
> 'resources/audio/xxxxx/someaudio.mp3'.replace(/\bxxxxx(?=\/[^/]+$)/, 'yyyy')
"resources/audio/yyyy/someaudio.mp3"
> 'resources/audio/xxxxx/anotheraudio.mp3'.replace(/\bxxxxx(?=\/[^/]+$)/, 'yyyy')
"resources/audio/yyyy/anotheraudio.mp3"
```

Comment: Why do you use the capturing group? Would it work to just replace the directory name by itself (i.e., `'path/to/file.mp3'.replace(/\/to\//, 'the')`)?

Comment: @andyg0808, What if `/to/` is occur twice? I used capturing group/lookahead to match only the parent directory of the file.